# Variable does not have a value

Tags: java, android, variables

After getting variable from other activity with method, I have problem using it for further coding.

I am getting variable like this:

```
public void setBank(String bank){
        selectedBank=bank;
        System.out.println(bank);
    }
```

with println checking what I got and "saving" it to the selectedBank variable, which I declared at the start of the class like this `public String selectedBank="";`

Entire code:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper  {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "bankomati_db.sqlite";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public String selectedBank="";

    public MyDatabase(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    public void setBank(String bank){
        selectedBank=bank;
        System.out.println(bank);
    }
//other methods
    }
```

This does not work, when I check selectedBank in some other method it is juts "".

How can I "save" variable from method setBank so I could use it in other methods.

EDIT:
this is my method where I need my variable(selectedBank).

```
 public List<String> getBankomatLocation(){


    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    //String [] sqlSelect={"0 _id", "Banka", "Naslov", "Posta", "Kraj"};
    String [] sqlSelect={"0 _id", "Naslov"};
    String sqlTables = "Bankomati_db";
    System.out.println("selectedBank:" + selectedBank);
    String [] args ={selectedBank};

    List<String> bankomati = new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor c = db.query(false, sqlTables, sqlSelect, "Banka=?", args, null, null, null, null, null);
    //Cursor c = db.query(false, sqlTables, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            bankomati.add(c.getString(1));
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    c.close();
    db.close();

    return bankomati;

}
```

Is it possible when method getReadableDatabase is called it also sets variable to ""?

Comment: make u sure you are using a concrete object of type MyDatabase and you should call the setbank method before checking selectedBank value in other methods.

Comment: Can you please post the code where you are actually using this class?  What you have looks like it should work so my guess is you are using it incorrectly (or there is some conflict).

Comment: You'd have to ensure that (a) you're looking at the same instance, (b) it hasn't been recreated by Android itself based on app lifecycle events, etc.

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Is your `getBankomatLocation()` method in your `MyDatabase` class?

Comment: It is in MyDatabase class, I have two methods in this class, the one in question up abowe, and one that is used before the setBank method is called in other Activity, with first I populate spinner and then save selection with button using setBank method like this `String bank=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                db.setBank(bank);`

Answer (score -2):

You have to make sure that you using the `this`. keyword to make sure that the value you change will stay change in the class. Later make to ask for the value later after you call the `setBank()` method. I took liberty of trying your code without the implementation class and it worked in my end.

In this code that I try, I added a constructor method `public MyDatabase(String selectedBank)` in order to test it in the main function. Here is the code that I try.

```
public class MyDatabase {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "bankomati_db.sqlite";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public String selectedBank = "";

    public MyDatabase(String selectedBank){
        //this.selectedBank = selectedBank;

    }

    public void setBank(String bank){
        this.selectedBank = bank;
        System.out.println(bank);
    }
    //other methods

    //This is to test the values of the variable 'selectedBank'     
    public static void main(String[] args){
       //Create new object MyDatabase to test the value of the "selectedBank"
       MyDatabase d = new MyDatabase("");

       //print the name of the bank in the method
       d.setBank("My Bank");

       //I can access the name of the bank after calling the method
       System.out.println(d.selectedBank);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't worry about the constructor. I put it to test the code and see the result. the most important is to change this.selectedBank = bank;

Comment: `You have to make sure that you using the "this." keyword to make sure that the value you change will stay change in the class.` nonsense

Comment: You don't have to use the `this` keyword to access class variables, you only need to do it when you want to set a class variable to a local variable of the same name. It is (in my opinion) better practice to always use `this` though